# How many adherents does Haymanot (version of Judaism from Ethiopia) have nowadays?

Tags: heterodox, ethiopian-beta-israel

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel);

> The population of [Beta Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel) is;
> Israel: 160,500 (2021), Ethiopia: 12,000 (2021), US: 1,000 (2008).

> They practise a non-Talmudic form of Judaism that is similar in some respects to Karaite Judaism. In Israel, this form of Judaism is referred to as Haymanot.

> The Ethiopian Jewish community in Israel is mostly composed of Beta Israel (practising both Haymanot and Rabbinic Judaism).

I want to know how many adherents does Haymanot have nowadays?
(This number is obviously not going to include Beta Israel people who practise Rabbinic Judaism)

Comment: I think this is off topic, as it is about Jews, not Judaism, sorry!

Comment: @RabbiKaii it's about Jews' practice of Judaism.

Comment: @msh210 thanks for clarifying

Comment: I'm reopening per this comment which has 5 upvotes and best represents meta consensus and standing site practice as far as I can tell. Anyone who disagrees is welcome to discuss there https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/non-normative-jewish-practices/5415#comment17178_5413

Comment: My impression (I don't have any cites, sorry) is that it does not exist independent of rabbinic Judaism anymore. Today many (most?) Beta Israel practice rabbinic Judaism and continue to perpetuate היימנות practices as custom where it does not contradict rabbinic Judaism. Where it does contradict it, those practices have ceased/been suspended. This is a fairly reductionist description, for a more comprehensive presentation of this syncretic approach see R. Sharon Shalom's [Shulhan ha-Orith](https://kotar.cet.ac.il/KotarApp/Viewer.aspx?nBookID=101787546)